# Foreign Key mapping using model mapper

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am getting a JSON which is deserialised into a POJO and I am trying to map a POJO to below entity class using modelmapper and trying to save these entities into the database.All the fields are getting mapped and saved as expected except the foreign key value which is coming as null. Also, the userid is auto generated.Can you please help me how can I save the user id in vehicle table using modelmapper??

My `User` Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
class User{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long userId;
        private String username;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Vehicle> vehicles= new ArrayList<>();
        //getters and setters
}
```

My `Vehicles` Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
class Vehicle{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long vehicleId;
    private String vehicleName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk" , nullable = false)
    private User user;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

My ModelMapping class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public void saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails
        User targetuser{
            UserDetails sourcePojo= userDetails
            User  targetEntity= targetuser
            ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            modelMapper.map(sourcePojo, targetEntity);

            userDetailsService.save(targetEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you mapping the models? The current code is correct, it shouldn't be any problem. (**PS** : make sure you have the  `getUser()` and `setUser()` in `Vehicle` class.

Comment: added the mapping

Comment: I have the getters and setter ,all the values are getting mapped and saved but in the column user_fk the value getting saved is null

Comment: What are `sourceEligibilityReqMsg` and `targetEligibilityPayer` ? the source is your Pojo and the target is the Model ?

Comment: Please check now @Sebastian.That was a typo.Its actually sourcePojo and targetEntity

Comment: Can you show me how are you calling the `saveEligibilityRequest` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206833/discussion-between-sebastian-csvean-and-gitesh).

Comment: I am just passing the userdetails pojo by calling it from the main class.And the userDetailsPersistenceService.save(targetEntity) method used is of springdatajpa repository

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with making annotation more specific this :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", 
               targetEntity = Vehicle.class,
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles= new ArrayList<>();
```

And

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk" , 
                referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                nullable = false)
    private User user;
```

And I think you have to remove annotation for auto generation of userid
As per my understanding issue is due to Auto generation of userid is done while saving an entry to DB. But when we mapped userid to vehicle it is null as it is not generated.

Comment: How will it identify the autogenerated userid in vehicle table .Will it resolve that autogenerated id itself.Or do I need to set the userid in the vehicle table explicitly.??

Comment: I have the getters and setter ,all the values are getting mapped and saved but in the column user_fk the value getting saved is null.

Comment: @Girish Do you geeing same issue after using above annotation?